# GCM not working for release .apk - Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services, android-c2dm

I have been using GCM without problem while debugging my app. Whenever I generate a signed .apk for release, the GCM stops working. It seems as if no data is sent or received by the GCM. I am completely lost because whenever I run the app to debug it to see the problem, it works fine since the GCM works for the debug version of my .apk. I am completely lost at what to do to get this to work. I have searched various Stack Overflow answers but none seem to fit what I am going through.

Also I have checked all the areas (that I know of) where the problem could exists (Google Developer's Console apis and persmissions, code, Google Docs) and everything seems to line up. What is going on?

Comment: Do you use proguard on your release build ? Are the [default recommended rules](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html)  set up correctly ?

Comment: @DeepakBala Yes I do use progaurd for release and I only have 4 rules suppressing warnings.

Comment: Can you post the logcat with the GCM log messages ? The GCMIntentService is probably being mangled when proguard is done with it. You can verify this by using [dex2jar](https://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/) and [jd-gui](http://jd.benow.ca/) to look at the class names post passing the jar through proguard.

Comment: @DeepakBala The problem is that the GCM doesn't work only in the release build. So I cannot debug it on android studio. When I run the debug version the GCM functions as it should. Is it that I can use these jars to solve this problem?

Comment: You don't have to debug anything to get a reverse-engineered class file from a `.apk` file. If the name of your `GCMIntentService` has changed in the APK, your problem has been identified.

Comment: @DeepakBala I have ran the command and gotten the .jar file that comes from it. Can you tell me what I am supposed to be looking for in with the jd-gui?

Comment: Check if the GCMIntentService.class can be found in the jar. If it has been renamed, Android will be unable to find it.

Comment: Have you solved your issue? I'm noticing the same issue even if I explicitly add `keep class com.example.MyGcmService`.